# multiple ajax call to single function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 3 ajax call. Data from each ajax call is passed to `john_doe();`

**Call 1**

```
$.ajax({
        url: url1,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
      }).success(function(data1){

    john_doe(data1);
});
```

**Call 2**

```
$.ajax({
        url: url2,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
      }).success(function(data2){

    john_doe(data2);
});
```

**Call 3**

```
$.ajax({
        url: url3,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
      }).success(function(data3){

    john_doe(data3);
});
```

**Main function**

```
function john_doe(param){
console.log(param); //Print data from all three ajax call.
}
```

How to separate data1, data2 and data3 in john_doe function? because I need to carry out arithmetic operation.

Currently,

**Input**

```
data1 = one,two,three
data2 = four
data3 = five
```

**Output**

console.log(param) would give output as

```
one
four
five
```

**I want output as**

```
console.log(param[0])
console.log(param[1])
console.log(param[2])

param[0] containing one,two,three
param[1] containing four
param[2] containing five
```

I dont have control over the data. How to access data1, data2 and data3 separately?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate" ?

Comment: change your john_doe function to take another parameter that identify the fisrt paramater ?

Comment: @Sorikairo right now single console.log(param) prints data coming from data1, data2 and data 3. so I get value1, value2 and value3. Whereas value1 is coming from data1, value 2 from data2 and so on.

Comment: I don't get your point, yes, that's how it's supposed to work, and ?

Comment: @Sorikairo I did try doing john_doe(param1,param2,param3) but then how do I tell Ajax Call 1, 2 and 3. That john_doe(data1) to be param1 and so on?

Comment: Is there anything in data1, data2, and data3 that can distinguish which data the response corresponds to? If not, I'd recommend @Sorikairo's method of adding an extra parameter, as in `$.ajax({ ... }).success(function (data1) { john_doe(1, data1); });` where john_doe has a function signature of `function john_doe (requestId, param) {}`

Comment: @MurlidharFichadia, do you mean you want to do data1+data2+data3 (for example) in john_doe()?

Comment: You can add a parameter to john_doe(data, param), such as john_doe(data, "firstParam") and add a if (param == "firstParam") do things

Comment: I have updated my question, please check input and output. At the start data came from 3 sources all passed to same function became one, but I need them back as 3 different variables

Comment: what are you trying to do with these 3 different variables? There is an easier solution than all the answers shown using ajax promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution is simply pass in an identifier, why is this dirty because it isn't really extensible with respect to adding say 4th or 5th call each time you do this you need to add more identifiers and your if statement in the main method will end up pretty ugly at one point.  But that said sometimes "Keeping It Simple" is ok.

Main function:

```
function john_doe(identifier, param) {

    // best to use something more readable then numbers
    if(identifier == 1) {    
       console.log(param); //Print data from all ajax call 1.
    } else if(identifier == 2) {
       console.log(param); //Print data from all ajax call 2.
    } else if(identifier == 23) {
       console.log(param); //Print data from all ajax call 3.
    } else {
       // handle bad id
    }
}
```

In your ajax calls, pass in the right identifier, for example **Call 2**:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url2,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
      }).success(function(data2){

    // numeric 2 in in the first param is your identifier
    john_doe(2,data2); });
```

Answer (score 9):

Using promises you can access all the data in Promise.all() callback and do whatever you need with it all at once. Assumes using jQuery 3+. Can use `$.when` in older versions

```
  var urls =['data-1.json','data-2.json','data-3.json'];
  // array of ajax promises
  var reqPromises = urls.map(function(url){
    return $.ajax({
       url: url,
       dataType: "JSON",
       type: "GET"
    });
  });

  Promise.all(reqPromises).then(function(res){
     // res is array of all the objects sent to each `$.ajax` from server
     // in same order that urls are in
     var param = res.map(function(item){
       return item.val
     });

     console.log(param)
  })
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tQkce0ywdDLmRevcdQCt?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: I can't even begin to explain how many questions I have asked in regards to handling this type of behavior; this is great!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a param to let you know where it is being called from

**Call 1**

```
$.ajax({
        url: url1,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
      }).success(function(data){

    john_doe('call1',data);
});
```

**Call 2**

```
$.ajax({
        url: url2,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
      }).success(function(data){

    john_doe('call2',data);
});
```

**Call 3**

```
$.ajax({
        url: url3,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
      }).success(function(data){

    john_doe('call3',data);
});
```

**Main function**

```
function john_doe(call,data){
    console.log('Called from : ' + call);
    console.log(data); //Print data from all three ajax call.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
Declare an object container to hold your response data values and your arithmetic operation function.

```
var myParams = {
    all_params: [],
    getParams: function(){
        return this.all_params;
    },
    setParam: function(index, data){
        this.all_params[index] = data;
    },
    yourArithmeticOperation: function(){
        console.log(this.all_params); // your actual logic using all 3 ajax response data
    }
}
```

Then, in your ajax calls:

```
// call 1
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "GET",
}).success(function(data){
   myParams.setParam(0, data); // add ajax 1 response data
});

// call 2
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "GET",
}).success(function(data){
   myParams.setParam(1, data); // add ajax 2 response data
});

// call 3
$.ajax({
    url: url1,
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "GET",
}).success(function(data){
   myParams.setParam(2, data); // add ajax 3 response data
});
```

In case you need all your response data,

```
// after all three ajax calls
params = myParams.getParams();
console.log(params);
```

And finally, your arithmetic operation,

```
myParams.yourArithmeticOperation();
```

Answer (score -3):

try adding `async: false` to your ajax calls

```
$.ajax({
        url: url1,
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
      }).success(function(data){

    john_doe('call1',data);
});
```

Comment: never ever use `async: false`. It has always been a terrible practice and is now deprecated by browser vendors and will throw warnings in console