# Loop through ajax get request and (store in a variable) console all response at end of completion of last ajax request.(with active IO)

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
var arrCollection = [];

var arrUrl = { "0" : ["1475432", "1475434", "1475436", "1475437", "1475440", "1475441", "1475442", "1475443", "1475444", "1475445", "1475446", "1475447"] };

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.when(ajaxRequest()).done(function(response){
        $.each(arrCollection, function(i, e){
           $("#show").append('<div id="innerDiv">'+i+'</div>');
        });
        console.log(arrCollection);
    });
  });
});

async function ajaxRequest() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred(); 
        $.each(arrUrl[0], async function(i, e){
            let url = "https://example.com/"+e;
            await $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: 'GET',
                //async: false,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': "bearer " + "1b7c79526bbb8effd1ce720c41910d22",
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                success: function(result){
                    arrCollection[i] = result;
                    deferred.resolveWith(result);
                },
                error: function(){
                    deferred.reject();
                }
            });
        });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

[image]

I get the value but sometimes it shows only some responses.
In synchronous ajax IO is inactive but want active IO.
I tried in synchronous and asynchronous both.

Comment: I found the answer. It does what I need.   https://stackoverflow.com/a/43309753/14028008